# How can I find a td class in a string? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

```
string="<td class=\"en\">enenene</td><td class=\"ro\">rorororo</td>";
```

Example:

```
 string.$('td.ro').html();
```

Comment: You cannot have a space between `<` and `td`. [That's not valid HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags), and jQuery is not able to parse it. Use a regex to get rid of the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way. Pretty dirty though!

```
var string = "<td class='en'>enenene</td><td class='ro'>rorororo</td>";
var h = $(string);
h.each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("class") == "ro"){
       //We've found the td
    }
});
```

See the dome on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/bMfqj/

Comment: brad's solution is much better.

Comment: @Vivin - Yes the new edited one is better, however in his actual answer he used `find` instead of `filter` and `find` works on when the element exits in the DOM. Please read the comments in his answer. Cheers.

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. I thought he changed it `filter` early on. Oh well nm.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(string).filter('td.ro').html();
```

Comment: It doesn't. The `find` doesn't return anything :( I was going to post this as a solution, but I tried it out in Firebug and it didn't work.

Comment: ya, find must be actually walking the dom... i just took a guess,  If you appended this to the dom it'd work

Comment: @brad `filter()` instead of `find()`. However, `$(string)` doesn't work because of the spaces between `<` and `td`.

Comment: hmmm... ya those spaces weren't in his original posting

Comment: sorry, ignore my previous comments about appending to the dom, this answer now works, again thanks to Sime

Answer (score 1):

Using a `find` by itself doesn't work. But if you have well-formed HTML, you can use jQuery's `parseXML` function:

```
var str = "<div><td class=\"en\">enenene</td><td class=\"ro\">rorororo</td></div>";
var xml = jQuery.parseXML(str);
var $xmlDoc = jQuery(xml);

console.log($xmlDoc.find("td.ro"));
```

**Note:** This only works in jQuery 1.5 and later.

**EDIT**: Actually you can use `filter` (look at brad's solution). That's probably what you want.